# Does firebase deploy have a bundle size limit?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I'm running into an issue where, when deploying,

```
firebase deploy --only functions,hosting
```

if my bundle size large, the deployment fails and throws and error.

[image]
If the bundle is less than 100mb, it works. Is there some upload limit to Firebase hosting?

FYI, the reason the bundle is so large is that I'm prerendering 1000s of pages during the build (Next.js SSG).

Comment: I don't think it's limited to 100mb.  Something else is going wrong.  Try running the command with --debug to get more information, and if you don't get an actionable error message out of it, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I am seeing a few places where a 100MB limit for the index.js file is called out as a blocker for Next.js on Firebase. The limits documentation says that a single function upload can be 100MB compressed and 500MB uncompressed.

Comment: Hi @Doug Stevenson and all people, could you help in this: im deploying more than 900 paths with 3 languages using nextjs + firebase hosting ; resulting in codebase directory with 512 Mb . that excceds the limits : so how to deal with this? thks in advance